# Testing a vue-componet which uses a filter

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have the following component:

```
<template>
    <div class="lead-segment">
        <div v-html="insuranceType()"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
 import Vue from 'vue';

 export default {
   name: 'lead-segment',
   props: {
     rowData: {
       type: Object,
       required: true,
     },
     rowIndex: {
       type: [Number, String],
     },
   },
   methods: {
     insuranceType() {
       const contribution = Vue.filter('currencyFilter')(this.rowData.additionalCustomerInfo.contribution);
       return `${this.rowData.leads.insurance_type.name}<br/>${contribution}`;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And the following test, written in karma/jasmine with vue-test-utils.

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import LeadSegmentComponent from './LeadSegmentComponent';
import { currencyFilter } from '../filters';

describe('LeadSegmentComponent', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.filter('currencyFilter', currencyFilter);

  const wrapper = shallowMount(LeadSegmentComponent, {
    localVue,
    propsData: {
      rowData: {
        additionalCustomerInfo: {
          contribution: 1,
        },
        leads: {
          insurance_type: {
            name: '',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
  const vm = wrapper.vm;

  it('should be build', () => {
    expect(vm)
      .toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

If I execute the test I am getting the following error:

"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue___default.a.filter(...) is not a function\n

If I remove the filter used in the component the test passes.

Why is Vue.filter not a function although I added it to the test? And what is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem.

So far I solved by importing in my test code Vue, and registering the filter globally. I do not like it, I would prefer not polluting global scope, but declaring it on "localVue" does not seems to work:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import myFilter from './myFilter';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    Vue.filter('myFilter', myFilter);
    // test code...
});
```